# How to retrieve the id of the new entry i just created with laravel RessourceApiController?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to return the id of the new entry i just created in my ToDoList table.

**ToDoListController.php**

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    ToDoList::create([

        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'state' => $request->input('state'),
        'closed' => $request->input('closed'),
    ]);
    return response()->json(["id" => $id?], 200); 
}
```

**ToDoList.php**

```
    class ToDoList extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'state', 'closed' ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create variable with `ToDoList` model

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $todo = ToDoList::create([
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'state' => $request->input('state'),
        'closed' => $request->input('closed'),
    ]);
    return response()->json(["id" => $todo->id], 200); 
}
```